# How do I convert this to mongodb aggregate query?

Tags: sql, mongodb

SELECT prop_type , count(prop_type) As no_of_properties
from prop_type
JOIN prop_for_rent USING (prop_type)
GROUP BY prop_type;

prop_type and prop_for_rent are both tables. Then "prop_type" used for the JOIN and GROUP BY is an attribute name in both.

The expected result is for the query to count the number of properties in each property type.
And this is the result of the sql version of it
[Screenshot of sql query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvqIq.png)

So i need it to display the same prop_type and then the number of properties in each type in mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.prop_type.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "prop_for_rent",
      "localField": "prop_type",
      "foreignField": "prop_type",
      "as": "prop_for_rent_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$prop_for_rent_docs",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$prop_type",
      "no_of_properties": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kLILtGG-zCl)

Comment: Let me edit the question to that  and let me also try the query .Thank you

Comment: @Marss I update my answer

Comment: The original answer even worked after I made a few changes , thanks again !

Comment: Perfect! It would be great if you can accept this answer and give it a up vote.